# Javascript "Datedropper" fills in values in other input-forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have downloaded a "Jquery datedropper" and wanted it to implement it into my form, but sadly the javascript-Code dosen´t specify a formfield by an "id" or "name". [Picture of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il8cN.jpg)

So now in every field the datedropper is implemented.

The Code is like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- custom css -->
<link href="datedropper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- jQuery lib -->
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<!-- dateDropper lib -->
<script src="datedropper.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <form action="profil_update.php" method="post">
        Adresse:                <input id="adress" name="adress"><br>
        Hausnummer:             <input id="adressnumber" name="adressnumber"><br>
        Weitere Adresszeile:    <input id="adress2" name="adress2"><br>
        Stock:                  <input  id="floor" name="floor"><br>
        T&uuml;r:               <input  id="door" name="door"><br>
        Postleitzahl:           <input id="zipcode" name="zipcode"><br>
        Stadt:                  <input id="city" name="city"><br>
        Land:                   <input id="country" name="country"><br>
        Staat:                  <input id="state" name="state"><br>
        Telefonnummer:          <input id="phone" name="phone"><br>
        Geburtsdatum:           <input type="text" id="birthday" name="birthday" data-lang="de" data-default-date="01-01-1980" data-min-year="1930" data-format="d.m.Y" />
        <script>
            $('input').dateDropper();
        </script>
        <br>
        Geschlecht:     <input id="gender" name="gender"><br>
        Beziehungsstatus:   <input id="relationship" name="relationship"><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Profil vervollst&auml;ndigen">
    </form>

    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="&Uuml;berspringen">
        </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

It would be really nice if someone could help me. Greetings Sven

And, I´m a beginner+ at programming.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but DreamWeaver is terrible. Please consider using a different IDE or simply go with Notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you would only want this on the Geburtsdatum field, so

```
$('#birthday').dateDropper();
```

is how you would target that.